# Sum of all values from dynamically created edittexts

Tags: android

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmNMK.png)

I need to add the editexts values, like in a billing app, and to store this data in shared preferences.

As shown in the image I need to add all of the editexts (empty) values and then disply the sum in Result field. Just like that others, Ety cage, Load, Ld Cage..

Please someone help me..

createTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n",})
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.weight = 3.0f;
            params.setMargins(10,0,10,0);
           // ll.setPadding(5, 1, 10, 0);
            final TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            final EditText txtLoad = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            final EditText txtLoad1 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            final EditText txtLoad2 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            final EditText txtLoad3 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());


            txt.setText( ""+(j + 1));
            txt.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt.setTextSize(20);

            txtLoad.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            txtLoad.setHint("Empty");
            txtLoad.setPadding(5, 0, 1, 0);
            int txtloadid = j+10;
            txtLoad.setLayoutParams(params);
            txtLoad.setId(txtloadid);

            txtLoad1.setHint("Ety Cage");
            int txtload1id = j+50;
            txtLoad1.setId(txtload1id);

            txtLoad2.setHint("Load");
            int txtload2id = j+100;
            txtLoad2.setId(txtload2id);

            txtLoad3.setHint("Ld Cage");
            int txtload3id = j+150;
            txtLoad3.setTextSize(18);
            txtLoad3.setId(txtload3id);

            ll.addView(txt);
            ll.addView(txtLoad);
            ll.addView(txtLoad1);
            ll.addView(txtLoad2);
            ll.addView(txtLoad3);

            //Add fields to LinearLayout defined in XML
            mainLinear.addView(ll);
            count++;
            j=count;
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create a new edittext for which you want to refer the value you can set a tag for it.

Also maintain a list of tags. That way you later you can use to iterate.

1. Set Tags on view using view.setTag() and keep a record of tags in a list.
2. iterate the list of tags and refer to your views using findViewWithTag()
3. While iterating you can access the values in your edittext

Comment: Unfortunately no, but you can look for search for samples on github

Answer (score 0):

Add all your EditText in an ArrayList.

```
List<EditText > editTexts - new ArrayList<>();
```

Once you have this value in your arraylist simply iterate through array List and add values.

```
int sum = 0;
for(EditText editText: editTexts) {
    String sTextFromET = editText.getText().toString();
    int nIntFromET = new Integer(sTextFromET ).intValue();
    sum =+ nIntFromET 
}
```

Comment: where should i add this on create of edittext or on the sum button,..  I have four edittext how it will work for all..

Comment: When you want to show Sum. Do you want to update it on editbox value change